# Iterating over keys in data script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to figure out how to compare user input value from a dropdown menu with an objects of IDs with the keys matching the dropdown's options in Vue.

*Example:*

```
<template>  
  <select v-model="selectMenu">  
    <option v-for"select in selections">{{ selection }}</option>  
  </select>  
</template>  

<script>  
export default {  
  data() {
    return {  
      selectMenu: '', 
      selections: [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ],  
      ids: {
        one: 'dfs745jfdb',
        two: 'adfjdsh3gf5',
        three: 'ag23dsgnsj'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I figured out how to do this a much easier way. i'm very new to vue and coding in general. What I did was combine selections and id's into a single array like this:
 *Solution:*

```
<template>  
  <select v-model="selectMenu">  
    <option v-for"selectId in selectIds" v-bing:value="selectId.id">
    {{ selectId.text }}
    </option>  
  </select>  
</template>  

<script>  
export default {  
  data() {
    return {  
      selectMenu: '', 
      selectIds: [
        { text: 'one', id: 'dfs745jfdb' },
        { text: 'two' id: 'adfjdsh3gf5' },
        { text" 'three' id: 'ag23dsgnsj' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.ids[this.selectMenu]` should give you the object in ids object.

Comment: so it would be say
idMatch: this.ids[this.selectMenu]

Comment: tried it and now the select menu that is pulling the options from the selections array won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Object.keys(this.ids).forEach(x => ... /* do stuff with this.ids[x] */)
```

Comment: tried this as well and it also made my drop down menu select items disappear (are being pulled from the selections array) doesn't make much sense. Not using the array at all, and to test even created a whole know variable to compare id's with, not even associated with the selection menu, and still disappears.